# Task.Factory.StartNew not always working with StartInfo

Tags: c#

I have an exe file I'm calling with `p.StartInfo`. This exe takes some time till it finishes, so in the meanwhile I want a 'Wait' window to be on top, and not modal (so the GUI stays responsive).
So this is my code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Process[] FileProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("SomeFile.exe");

    if (FileProcess.Length == 1)
        wait_debug.ShowDialog();
});

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "SomeFile.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = work_directory;
p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
p.Start();
```

The problem is the wait_debug window is not always shown, and this is strange, because in the task manager the SomeFile.exe IS running, but nevertheless, the wait window is not shown. It's hard to 'catch' the failures with the debugger, and so far I did not manage doing so. Some times it pops up, sometimes it doesn't. very annoying.

Any idea why, or what is a better solution?

btw, I'm using .Net 4 (I know some solutions only work with 4.5).
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you start a task to check for a process then you start the process.  To me this is a classic race condition where sometimes the process will start before your task checks for it and sometimes it checks before you start it.

Comment: I think, in some cases `p.Start();` happens after the `if (FileProcess.Length == 1)` check. Maybe placing `Task.Factory.StartNew` call after starting the process will help...